# PHP Memcache - Dynamic sites

Tags: php, memcached

My question main is based on reading up on memcache.

In one blog i read the best way to implement this is by creating a key based on the MD5 hashing of the SQL query.

example:

```
$key = md5("SELECT * FROM memcached_test where name='ashley'");
$get_result = $memcache->get($key);
```

on sites i have worked with this is impractical as the query itself is using the PDO MySQL so the key would look like this:

```
$key = md5("SELECT * FROM memcached_test where name=?");
$get_result = $memcache->get($key);
```

so the key generated would be the same regardless.

What is the most practical way to generate the key for memcache? What is classed as good practice using memcache?

Comment: Bear in mind in your code you have a couple of syntax errors. You should use `$memcache->get($key);` rather than `$memcache>get($key);`

Comment: @JonathonHenderson Thank you for your note. I copied this directly from the blog and didn't notice the syntax error. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer fairly readable keys, so I've personally used a something like '`memcache_test:ashley:otherpart`'. If the key(s) are likely to me more complex than a simple word, a simple escaping of them will also be useful, like '`urlencode()`', which would usually suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your input, based on your comment, as i haven't done much work with memcache or memcached would you recommend using the memcache code directly with the database class or with the page requesting the database?

Comment: Caching is an optional layer above the database, that calls the actual SELECT only if it doesn't have the appropriate data in the cache. Ideally, it would also be a layer below the page itself, but I can appreciate that the full layering of code can be more than is required (So can a cache, if its not required). PS - please upvote answers you find useful.

Comment: don't worry i was doing i just wanted people to expand on there answers. Thanks for the additional information. I was aware it acts as a sort of abstraction layer between the script and the database. Caching the results of the mysql to avoid the script being reparsed by the web-server. At least this is what i beleive it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Personally if I'm grabbing a record from a database table I like to make the key as follows:

```
$appPrefix = "myapp"; // An identifier for my application
$tableName = "table"; // database table name
$recordId = "1"; // The record I'm interested in

// Query: SELECT * FROM `$tableName` WHERE id = '$recordId';
$record = $memcache->get($appPrefix . ":" . $tableName . ":" . $recordId);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, based on your comment, as i haven't done much work with memcache or memcached would you recommend using the memcache code directly with the database class or with the page requesting the database?